Why python wiremock doesnt respect precision and returns numbers as string?
I am trying basic mock example on decimals using wiremock and I couldn't get it to work. And I dont see any example online either.  Below is the response section of my  json file
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "weekly_rate": "{{randomDecimal lower=100.00 upper=800.00 precision=2}}",
      "max_amount": "{{randomDecimal lower=5000.00 upper=20000.00 precision=2}}"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }

and I get this response
{
  "weekly_rate": "220.87939761296946",
  "max_amount": "8860.916637737479"
}

Two issues

The numbers have more than 2 decimal places so the precision is not
respected.
The numbers are strings instead of numeric



Neither the docs nor the code indicate that there is a precision argument. 2. You put it into quotation marks.


where are the docs specific to decimal? Also I tried without quotes and it complains.

removed precision and tried. I still get the same result as well

I looked in to this already https://docs.wiremock.io/response-templating/random-values/  but I am still facing the same issues

To remove the quotes you will need to switch to the body element instead of the jsonBody element

This was answered on the WireMock Community Slack so posting here for completeness.
To force the decimal value generated by the randomDecimal helper to 2 decimal places you need to combine the randomDecimal helper with the numberFormat helper:
{{numberFormat (randomDecimal lower=100.00 upper=800.00) '###.00' 'en_GB'}}

The reason the decimals are generated as strings is because the jsonBody element requires valid json to be used.  Unfortunately, because the handlebars template engine uses {{ and }} this generates invalid json if you don't put quotes around them.  To workaround this you can switch to the body element instead of the jsonBody element.  The body element takes a string which means you can create the response without quotes around the helpers:
"weekly_rate": {{numberFormat (randomDecimal lower=100.00 upper=800.00) '###.00' 'en_GB'}}

